# Mongoose tagging model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, tags

I'm trying to model a structure for my a new project of mine. I come from a relational database background and I'm trying to understand how to best model a relationship where for example a post can have many tags. The use cases that I have are the following:

- A user can create/edit a post
- When creating/editing the post the user can search for existing tags or add new ones
- The user can see each related tags when viewing a post
- The user can see each related post when viewing a tag

What I got so far are the following models

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  post: String,
  tags: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tag'
  }],
  updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

const TagSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

**Question 1**: Would this be a good setup for my use case?

The pros that I can see are that I can easily search for news tags using the tag model and that each tag are unique. The problem I've been having is that I'm not really sure on how to handle the request when a user creates/updates a post.

Currently I have the following logic in my post#create endpoint

```
Post.create(req.body, (err, text) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' });
  } else {
    const newTags = req.body.tags.filter(tag => tag._id === undefined && tag.name);
    Tag.init().then(() => {
      Tag.create(newTags.map(tag => tag.name), (err, tags) => {
        tags.forEach(tag => { text.tags.push(tag) });
        text.save();
      })
    });
    res.send(text);
  }
});
```

A request body on this endpoint could look something like

```
{
  "post": "Post message",
  "tags": [
    { "_id": "1234" }, // Existing tag
    { "name": "my tag" } // New tag
  ]
}
```

**Question 2**: Is there some better/easier way to achieve this than the above code?

Comment: Why do you need tag ids? tag is a string, unique by definition. "a post can have many tags" can be done literally - `tags: [String]`. Having a dedicated schema for tags makes little sense to me.

Comment: @AlexBlex For me it felt natural to give them ids since I wanted each tag to be unique and resusable. So if two posts would contain the same tag they just had a reference to the tag instead of keeping the data in both places.

I also want the user to be able to search through each distinct tag when adding/editing a post which for me feels more natural to do if tags are a model itself.

Comment: Sorry it was an advice to embed tags into posts in the form of rhetorical question =)  You don't need the extra collection, normalisation, references etc. It feels natural in SQL, not in mongo.

Comment: @AlexBlex no need to be sorry, I'm very open to suggestions! I just tried to explain my reasoning behind the decision of creating a separate model for the tags. For me it feels a bit weird that I would be forced to search for existing tags using the text model instead of just accessing them directly. But maybe thats the way mongo is supposed to work?

Comment: That's okay, you don't need to explain your feelings out loud unless you wish to. If you are not comfortable with the proposed approach, just ignore it.  There are ~250 other questions about tagged posts https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+post+tags  take a look for inspiration, or may be try free https://university.mongodb.com/ classes online to get better feeling of the db.

Comment: @AlexBlex how do you mean? I just explained it using my feelings as a base for my decisions. As I said I'm very open to suggestions and I agree with you that an array would be much nicer on the post level. I'm still wondering however how I would go ahead to find all tags if i would like to create a tag cloud for example.

Comment: will it not be better to do the logic on the client side : before validating the post you can add tags which is basically an array you get from the server avoiding any redundancies. When creating you just send the string + tagsId.

Comment: @cagliostro yea I thought about that as well, but it could get nasty if the post is invalid for some reason (when validated in the back-end) so I could end up with a number of tags that has no connections

Comment: @nbon understand but if you are creating a post before creating tags you can have a post  with some tags missing as tags is a document. If there is no ID before Post Creation you will have a problem no ?

Comment: @cagliostro yea thats true, can get ugly both ways. Think I'm gonna go with the nested array solution for now and see how it pans out. Cheers!

Comment: I was thinking what you can do is first validate the post without the newly created tags, then if no error create the new tags and third insert the new tags in the post.